# ¿Cómo hacer que este modal de bootstrap inicie automáticamente?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Me he pasado todo el día navegando por la red, en busca de la solución a este lío. Quiero hacer que este modal aparezca inmediatamente ingresen a la página y que NO LOS DEJE CERRARLA DANDOLE CLICK FUERA DEL MODAL. Pero por más que he intentado con otras soluciones, no he dado pie con bola y ya es estresante.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Velebit Travel Gallery || Inicio</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iconos/css/velebit-embedded.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iconos/css/velebit.css">
      <link rel="icon" href="media/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">¡Work in progress!</h5>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      ¡Lo sentimos! Esta página todavía se encuentra en construcción, y ninguno de sus contenidos está listo para ser consumido.
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Volver al inicio</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
           });
          </script>



          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
          <script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="JavaScript/main.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

¡Gracias, me quitáis un embrollo de cabeza bastante feo.

Comment: debes escribir `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
});` observa que faltaba el parámetro 'show' y debías usar ready() para asegurar que toda la página haya cargado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para abrir la modal al terminar la carga de la pagina, utiliza `$(document).ready`.
Para evitar el cierre de la modal, las propiedades son: `keyboard` y `backdrop`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

la funcionalidad de $(document).ready(callback) es la de ejecutar funciones una vez cargada en su totalidad una página web.Y para mostrar el modal bastará con invocar el método .modal()

```
$(document).ready(
  function (){
    $('#myModal').modal();
  }
);
```

Si quieres que se ejecute un tiempo después usa un timing

```
$(document).ready(
  function (){
    // Se mostrara el modal 1segundo despues de haber cargado la pagina
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            $('#myModal').modal();
        }, 1000);

  }
);
```